# Set enums in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I am trying to mimic enum like effects in Rails tests. However, I can not seem to get it to work.

Example.

I have a module called Days:

```
module Days    
   SUNDAY = 0;
   MONDAY = 1;
   TUESDAY = 2;
   WEDNESDAY = 3;
   THURSDAY = 4;
   FRIDAY = 5;
   SATURDAY = 6;
end
```

In the same directory, I have a scheduler_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Scheduler do
  include Days
  ...
```

However, Ruby throws the following error:

```
in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Days (NameError)
    from /Users/krg07/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:201:in `module_eval'
    from /Users/krg07/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:201:in `subclass' ...
```

Any idea how I could make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ruby doesn't have enum, but you can do something similiar like in the link
http://www.rubyfleebie.com/enumerations-and-ruby/

Comment: I agree. I tried something similar - I added these "enums" in a module, and tried including the module. However, the problem is that this module isnt found.

Comment: the link explains to put them in a class. or you could always use hashes :sunday => 1

Answer (score 0):

Your module must not be included in the Rails autoload paths or doesn't follow autoloading conventions. You can probably get around the issue by just requiring the file before you include it:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require './days'
describe Scheduler do
  include Days
```

Comment: I had a feeling that would fix it, but unfortunately, it cant find the constants. I get:


in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant MONDAY (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.1 has enums. I have just upgraded and started using it. Works like a charm!

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html